# ArcGIS Pro Model runs in ModelBuilder but “None of the processes are ready to run" when run as Geoprocessing Tool

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, geoprocessing-framework

I have a model which runs perfectly in ModelBuilder and validation shows all stages are ready to run. Bottom right, below, shows the model runs to completion.

[image: Model Validated and Run]

However, when I run as a custom geoprocessing tool after revalidating to make sure everything is ready to run I get the warning that "None of the processes are ready to run." and the tool fails to execute.

[image: Failed when run as a geoprocessing tool]

- I make no changes to the inputs or environment between the runs

What would cause this?

Comment: May be the issue are within your sub-models?

Answer (score 1):

After much testing, this appears to have been caused by referencing layers that were in a different map within the same project, rather than the map that was open when running the process. If you want to reference layers in a model make sure the map is open when you run as a geoprocessing tool. This is not an issue when running in ModelBuilder itself - hence the problem.